# Fill gaps in a time schedule

Tags: php

A daily schedule starts at 08:30 and ends at 17:00
(time represented via a begin 'nn:nn' string and end 'nn:nn' string).

Time blocks can only begin and end on :00, :15, :30, :45 of the hour.

A given schedule will have zero or more (non-overlapping) blocks of time pre-booked
(of variable block size--anything from one block of 8:30-17:00; or could be many small blocks of 15-minute, half hour, multi-hour blocks, etc).

Example Input:

```
$schedule = [
    [
        'begin' => '10:00',
        'end' => '12:30'
    ],
    [
        'begin' => '15:15',
        'end' => '16:00'
    ]
];
```

Example Output:

```
$gapFiller =
[
    [
        'begin' => '08:30',
        'end' => '10:00'
    ],
    [
        'begin' => '12:30',
        'end' => '15:15'
    ],
    [
        'begin' => '16:00',
        'end' => '17:00'
    ]
];
```

Create a function that returns an array of zero or more blocks to fill all the gaps present in an pre-booked schedule. Make block spans as large as possible without overlapping any other blocks.

```
function fillGaps($schedule){
    //code...

    return $gapFiller;
}

$gapFiller = fillGaps($schedule);
```

Comment: Is your input guaranteed sorted in ascending time blocks with no overlaps?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, pre-sorted and never overlaps.

Comment: It is a free coding service as I have (A)nswered with code 160 questions #onhere and not been paid a dime. :) I have asked a grand total one SO question—this one—and I did not post my own code because it was too convoluted, was going in the wrong direction and I did not want to burden the good people willing to help me tonight with it. I know you're just trying to keep the community/user base on track with policies and guidelines, I can appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will give you the desired result, based on the input being sorted with no overlaps:

```
function fillGaps($schedule) {
    $gaps = array();
    $time = strtotime('08:30');
    foreach ($schedule as $event) {
        if ($time < strtotime($event['begin']))
            $gaps[] = array('start' => date('H:i', $time), 'end' => $event['begin']);
        $time = strtotime($event['end']);
    }
    if ($time < strtotime('17:00'))
        $gaps[] = array('start' => date('H:i', $time), 'end' => '17:00');
    return $gaps;
}
```

Output for your sample data:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'start' => '08:30',
    'end' => '10:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'start' => '12:30',
    'end' => '15:15',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'start' => '16:00',
    'end' => '17:00',
  ),
)
```

Demo on [rextester](http://rextester.com/IJU96695)